# Ansible: Correct syntax for conditional in when

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to achieve the following `when` conditional:

```
    - name: Create file
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: /tmp/file.yaml
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0600'
      when: boolean_fact and ansible_host not in server_hosts
```

`server_hosts` is a fact containing a list of 3 specific hosts, out of a total of 8 cluster hosts.

The `when` condition should translate to: if `boolean_fact` evaluates `true` and `ansible_host` is not one of the 3 server hosts, create the template into other 5 agent hosts, otherwise, if `boolean_fact` evaluates `false`, create the template into all 8 hosts.

The play is executed against `cluster` inventory:

```
[server]
apollo
boreas
cerus

[agent]
chaos
crios
helios
hermes
hypnos

[cluster:children]
server
agent
```

Something like:

```
    - name: Create file
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: /tmp/file.yaml
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0600'
      when: (boolean_fact and ansible_host not in server_hosts) or not boolean_fact
```

The above condition works as intended, I just want to make sure is the correct way to implement it. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Does your play target `all` hosts? Do the *3 specific hosts* fall into into different groups of your inventory?

Comment: Yes, I use cluster, which includes the server hosts.

Comment: Please see if correctly targeting the hosts suits your requirement. E.g. `- hosts: server` (to target the group), or `- hosts: boreas,chaos,hermes` (if hosts don't belong to same group).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not clear where `server_hosts` is coming from and you are obviously interested in to find out to which group a host belongs to, it is recommend to use the [`group_names`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups).

For an **`inventory`** file with content of

```ini
[server]
apollo.example.com
boreas.example.com
cerus.example.com

[agent]
chaos.example.com
crios.example.com
helios.example.com
hermes.example.com
hypnos.example.com

[cluster:children]
server
agent
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: server
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    FACT: true

  tasks:

  - name: Am I in group?
    debug:
      msg: "Yes."
    when: FACT and 'server' in group_names
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook --inventory example.com main.yml
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Am I in group?] *****
ok: [apollo.example.com] =>
  msg: Yes.
ok: [boreas.example.com] =>
  msg: Yes.
ok: [cerus.example.com] =>
  msg: Yes.
```

For a playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    FACT: true

  tasks:

  - name: In which group I am?
    debug:
      msg: "{{ group_names }}"
    when: FACT and 'server' not in group_names
```

the result will be

```yaml
TASK [In which group I am?] ******
ok: [chaos.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - agent
  - cluster
ok: [crios.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - agent
  - cluster
ok: [hermes.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - agent
  - cluster
ok: [helios.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - agent
  - cluster
ok: [hypnos.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - agent
  - cluster
```

**Documentation**

- [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html)
- [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html)

You may also have a look into [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) since [`ansible_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_host) is a [Connection variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables) and you probably want to use [`inventory_hostname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-inventory_hostname) instead.